# C# BouncyCastle-How can I create a sha512ECDSA certificate and a valid certificate revocation list for this certificate?

Tags: c#, certificate, bouncycastle, sha512, ecdsa

How can I create a sha512ECDSA certificate and a valid certificate revocation list for this certificate using the latest version of BouncyCastle? I did not find any hints and the documentation does not seem to be well maintained either...

Comment: You have the source code, and maybe some Java examples.

Comment: The only thing I found is this link in Java: http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation  However, you cannot simply translate this to C# because the `PrivateKey` and `KeyPair` classes do not exist and the `SetSignatureAlgorithm` method is deprecated.

Comment: I've directly asked this question in Github, too: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/issues/179

Answer (score 0):

I did this now using OpenSSL directly. Here you can see the result: https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/2e423b06904615255c05fe9056e8704b